# Need to enable mod_rewrite on CentOS server with WHM

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, mod-rewrite

I have a CentOS VPS with WHM installed.

I can't seem to configure mod_rewrite in httpd.conf. Can someone point me in the right direction?

phpinfo:

http://www.winwebsolutionz.com/blog/phpinfo.php

Comment: Which ways did you try?

Comment: opened root server..Service Configuration-Apache Configuration Within Apache Configuration please look for Include Editor
  When you click on Include Editor , you'll be given 3 different choices.

Pre Main Include
Pre Virtual Host Include
Post Virtual Host Include

Comment: In your phpinfo(): the Apache httpd daemon seems to be manually compiled and the `--enable-rewrite` option is not there. Maybe I'm wrong...

Answer (score 2):

Just Check that Apache was compiled with mod_rewrite and then enable:

Mod_Rewrite is compiled with Apache by default on cPanel. EX:

```
root@server [~]# sudo httpd -l | grep rewrite
  mod_rewrite.c
```

You can enable it for an account through the .htaccess file with a line such as:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually cpanel(WHM) compiles mod_rewrite by default. So you must just activate it in your '.htaccess' using:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Also I'm not sure that you can see if mod_rewrite is activated by executing phpinfo()..

Comment: opened root server..Service Configuration-Apache Configuration Within Apache Configuration please look for Include Editor
  When you click on Include Editor , you'll be given 3 different choices.

Pre Main Include
Pre Virtual Host Include
Post Virtual Host Include ---The include we need to use in here is Pre Virtual Host Include . Please choose your apache version within Pre Virtual Host Include dropdown menu
added this code.............
RewriteEngine On

Comment: winwebsolutionz.com/blog ...i tried to configue custom permlinks in wordpress.so created .htaccess file with this code " # BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: If you've compiled apache, you can see if it's activated in the ./compile command line; it's the option `--enable-rewrite`. It seems it's manually compile and the `--enable-rewrite` option is not there. Maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: If your mod_rewrite is not compiled in, you will get 'Internal server error' if you add 'RewriteEngine or RewriteRule' to your .htaccess. 
If you have some of the directives above, and you don't get any 500-Internal server error, then your mod_rewrite is COMPILED/ENABLED.

Comment: when i added 'RewriteEngine' code to .htaccess file..getting this error..."Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@winwebsolutionz.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request"

Comment: Still iam waiting to get my problem solved..still suffering.any help would be highly helpful.

Comment: I tried via easyapache software.Selected profile and built it ..but still mod-rewrite not enabled..